# Error thrown in Microsoft Biztalk Intertop Component, when sending documents using a multiple root schema

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk

I've received a schema containing multiple root nodes from a customer, and an example XML file that contains a single root node. The nodes in the schema each reference each other, starting with the top node. I've created a map that uses this schema for use in BizTalk and deployed the map and schemas. However when sending the document through BizTalk, the following error is thrown:

> StackTrace:    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.DocumentSpec.get_TypeMetadata()
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.DocumentSpec.get_DocType()
>   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.MsgTypeSchema..ctor(IPipelineContext
>   pipelineContext, SchemaList envSpecName, SchemaList docSpecName)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.XmlDasmReader.CreateReader(IPipelineContext
>   pipelineContext, IBaseMessageContext messageContext,
>   MarkableForwardOnlyEventingReadStream data, Encoding encoding, Boolean
>   saveEnvelopes, Boolean allowUnrecognizedMessage, Boolean
>   validateDocument, SchemaList envelopeSpecNames, SchemaList
>   documentSpecNames, IFFDocumentSpec docSpecType, S

I'm unsure how to read it, but it would seem like the message is missing some needed metadata. The message is being suspended as well.

To give you an idea of how the schema looks in visual studio:

[image]

In BizTalk, each of the nodes are created as a separate schema, with a different root node, but the same target namespace, name and assembly. 
Why can't BizTalk route the document to the correct schema? Do I need to perform some changes to the current schema? The documents being sent all have a single root node with a target namespace included.

I've tried redeploying the maps and schemas, restarting host instances and removing/adding the target namespace, nothing has worked so far. There are a few schemas in BizTalk with the same root node, but a different target namespace. I'm unsure if these could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the schema, and in the Properties window look for an item called Root Reference and set that to the root element

[image: Root Reference item property]

If they have different namespaces, then no those won't cause an issue.